# Java Selenium - how to download file when "Save as" pop up shows up?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Java Selenium - how to download file when "Save as" pop up shows up?

How to click "Save" button and download file to desired location?

[image]

Comment: File upload/download dialog belongs to operating system, not the browser. You can not handle the dialog using selenium. To avoid the dialog you need to create new browser profile, set up to automatically download files of type do some folder. Once you achieve this browser behavivor just use the browser profile in your selenium test.

Comment: Could you show hot to do this ?

Comment: If you're using Google chrome, then navigate to settings and search for download in the search settings or navigate to downloads section. In that turn off "Ask where to save each file before downloading" and provide desired location for the downloads

Comment: but I want to do this in java selenium with a use of ChromeOptions class

Answer (score 0):

I'm having same situation, see details below

Hello,

I'm using Chrome  120.0.6099.225  with ChromeDriver 120.0.6099.109
Since yesterday when I run some of the tests from our suite the Save as pop-up appears to press Save or Cancel to confirm when downloading a file. This was working fine for weeks/months behind.

I use JAVA with Selenium and I do have these settings in my driver init class

```
Map<String,Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("download.default_directory", chromeDefaultDir);
prefs.put("savefile.default_directory",chromeDefaultDir);
prefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", false);
prefs.put("download.directory_upgrade", true);
prefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads",1);
prefs.put("safebrowsing.enabled", true);
prefs.put("disable-popup-blocking", true);

options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
```

What would be the reason of this and do you know what I could try to fix this ?

I want to not see that Save As popup, instead download to happen automatically in the default chrome folder as was happening before.

Comment: This is not an answer but a "me too".  You should either add a comment or ask your own question

Comment: Sorry Martin, my first comment here will remove this.